# Regex Substring preceded by a specific number of any character

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list from which I want to extract a part of text from those elements which have the following pattern:

`<Start of string><Less than 30 characters> advocate. versus`

I only want the `<Start of string><Less than 30 characters>` part

The code which I think should have worked but didn't:

`a = re.search('^.{,30}advocate. versus', text).group(1)`

and

`a = re.search('^(.{,30})advocate. versus', text).group(1)`

Apart from these, I also tried

`a = re.search('^(.*)advocate. versus', text).group(1)`

which worked, but I only want less than 30 characters, not just any number of characters.

Examples:

Consider the list with two items:

['Mr. Rajesh Bhardwaj, Advocate ..... Appellant Through Ms. Prem Lata Bansal, Sr. Standing Counsel with Mr.Vishnu Sharma, Advocate. versus PRADEEP KUMAR SAHNI ..... Respondent Through None', 'Mr.Vishnu Sharma, Advocate. versus JYOTI APPARELS']

I want to extract the text from second element which has less than 30 characters before "advocate. versus" but not text from the first one which has more than 30 characters. Basically, I want this from the second item:

`Mr.Vishnu Sharma,`

Ignore the case of the text in the list, assume everything is in lowercase.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are searching for. You need the zero in the quantifier {0,30}. And As I understood you dont want to capture the advocate versus part. You can use a lookahead for that. If will check if the advocate is there, but will not capture it. Dont use ^ at the start. because it mean "start of the line", your match is not at the start of the line. Also keep in mind - regex are case sensitive. "advocate" and "Advocate" are two different patterns. I made a regex that matches the indeferent of the case

As I understood the match you want has a comma before it, we can use it to extract exactly the value you want. Basically veverything after the comma and before advocate. versus.

```
(?<=,)[^,]{0,30},(?= [Aa]dvocate\. versus)
```

demo
https://regex101.com/r/cO5wcg/3